Locating an iframe in a closed shadow root
I am making a program that bypasses the cloudflare "Verify that you are human" check using Python, Selenium (and some javascript). The problem is that the checkbox element is located in a closed shadow root that's located in an iframe, that's located in a closed shadow root. The structure can be seen here by inspecting the checkbox.
So far, I managed to get into the first (outer) shadow root but cannot access the iframe in it.
This is my code:
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Inject script to force shadow DOMs open
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': """
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
"""})

# open the site
driver.get("https://annas-archive.org/slow_download/c9cc2ebc974bb1955881807bdca7807d/0/0")

# wait for the page to load properly
sleep(3)

# Access the outer shadow DOM
outer_shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#JStsl2 > div > div')
outer_shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', outer_shadow_host)

# locate the iframe
iframe = outer_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cf-chl-widget-xn7qb")

# Switch to the iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Access the inner shadow DOM
inner_shadow_host = outer_shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body')
inner_shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', inner_shadow_host)

# Find and interact with the target element inside the inner shadow root
target_element = inner_shadow_root.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[type="checkbox"]')
target_element.click()

To locate the iframe element I have tried:

Using By.TAG_NAME and By.XPATH
Making the element visible with the following line of code:
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display='block'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", iframe)


The "solution" (in quotes because in not the best solution). I found is this, but if you need to bypass Cloudflare maybe it don't work.
I didn't found other way to manage shadow-root closed.
This click website background to focus mouse, then TAB to reach the checkbox and Space to activate it.
You can adapt //body if you need
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body").click()
        
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
        
actions.perform()

