How to Resolve a Type Mismatch Error Getting a ShadowRoot Web Element
My eventual goal is to write a procedure to automate clearing some parts of my browser data. However, I'm having trouble getting to first base. I haven't worked with Shadow Roots until now. Does anyone see what I'm doing to raise a Type mismatch error in the following code?
Public Sub TestShadowRoot()

  Dim aCD As Selenium.ChromeDriver
  Dim aShadowHost As Selenium.WebElement
  Dim aShadowRoot As Selenium.WebElement

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Set aCD = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
  Call aCD.Get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")

  Set aShadowHost = aCD.FindElementByTag("settings-ui")
  Set aShadowRoot = aCD.ExecuteScript( _
    Script:="return arguments[0].shadowRoot", _
    arguments:=aShadowHost)

  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  Debug.Print (Err.Description)
End Sub

I expected the test code to return aShadowRoot Web Element. Instead, I got a Type mismatch error.

I founded a solution for shadow-root, it is not perfect but can help you to solve it. It's about click some background element and send X tabs keys until you get on the element you want and send Space key to activate, Example in answer (for python) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79060811/locating-an-iframe-in-a-closed-shadow-root/79061153#79061153

Thanks Wonka. I was able to implement your suggestion in Excel VBA after a fashion and produce a "workaround." That said, it would have been sweeter to get a solution to my code issue above.
